# browser shows script which I have deleted

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to test js function on this simple html. First run I got error and tried to fix it ,save page and load but alas I get the same old script no changes seen...tried many times...the totally removed the script tag ...but still browser shows my old script on the page with the same old error.....I closed browser and reopened it ...no effect ..tried all browsers..no effect

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to list all the items in the array.</p>
        <ul id="ull">
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need more info than what is provided to try to help you out with this one. What is the script your are trying to include? How are you testing this in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> if you are using Chrome or Firefox (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in Internet Explorer).

This will refresh any JavaScript and CSS that is saved in the browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS and JS resources are probably cached by your browser.

When you change and reload to test, try reloading using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the cache as part of that reload. This should work with all browsers.